# styled-jsx - is it possible to define css rules without a class name and why dynamically resolved styles don't work?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, next.js, css-in-js

I have the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import MainTemplate from '../components/MainTemplate';
import { H1, Card } from '@blueprintjs/core';
import css from 'styled-jsx/css';

export default () => {
    const { className, styles } = css.resolve`
     { color: red; }
    `;
    return (
        <MainTemplate>
            {styles}
            <Card className={className}>
                <H1>Some header text!</H1>
            </Card>
        </MainTemplate>
    )
}
```

As you can see, I want to pass a `className` to an external Card component. However, I see in the dev tools, that there is a style element added to the head, but it seems as if it has text inside it, rather than styles, to wit, the syntax inside it isn't highlighted. In the result, the styles aren't applied.

So I wonder what do I wrong? I use a resolve tag as it's said [in the documentation](https://github.com/zeit/styled-jsx#the-resolve-tag).

Also I wonder is it possible to define styles for element, without specifying a concrete tag name or class name?

I use `next.js` and styles aren't applied neither in dev nor in production mode.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I just used an inappropriate css rule for testing - `color` is overridden by the styles of `H1`, so I didn't see the effect. If I use `width` or `height` it works well. So it was just my mistake.

As for the second question, it works well without a concrete tag or class. One even doesn't have to add parenthesis, to wit, the following code

```
const { className, styles } = css.resolve`height: 100%;`;
return (
    <MainTemplate>
        {styles}
        <Card className={className}>
            <H1>Плееры</H1>
        </Card>
    </MainTemplate>
)
```

works well too.